# Tag 12-angry-men mistake

Tags: discussion

The tag 12-angry-men was created, and is used, on a question specifically about the 1957 movie. However, the 1997 film's description was approved for the tag wiki, overriding my rejection. We should prevent loosely-researched edits that present conflicting information.

Comment: That would have been my mistake. There should, however then, be separate tags for the two movies. Kill the one I did, that's for sure, or I can re-edit it. Thanks for the catch, as I am only trying to help this site be more complete. Trying to fill in the tags as I get time.

Comment: I have made the changes. Should be visible when peer reviewed again.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that this is unfortunate.

Its kind of hard to police that though.  Reviews go to several people.  We don't have any way other than the review process to stop bad content going through.

Do you want me to edit it?  Do you have any content to provide - if not I will just remove what is there, as you say its the wrong movie.